# NavigationController UIToolbar Change Items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I want to change the items in my `UIToolbar` by hiding the toolbar, changing the items (button, fixed space, etc), and revealing it again.

I currently have a button on my `UIToolbar` that, when pressed, hides the toolbar by calling `[[self navigationController]setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];`.

How can I set these items? Is it possible using interface builder or do I need to hard-code them in?

Comment: It is not possible using the IB for obvious reasons. You will need to add objects to the UIToolbar, set them to null (when hiding them) and re-assign them back to the UIToolbar when you want to show it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set new items for the toolbar this way:

```
[toolbar setItems:<new_items_array> animated:YES];
```

It will also animate the change so you may not need to hide and show it again, which is not a good UI practice in general.

Comment: I use this method and I can remove toolbar items but can't readd them.  Why is ths?

Answer (score 2):

This is non-standard behavior, but should be doable. You might consider instead of removing and adding new buttons to the existing toolbar, to instead create a different toolbar that gets faded in instead. This would make things easier to code/debug. In general, it just requires less "mess."

To achieve the desired behavior, you could do something like:

```
float animationDuration = .25;

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:*{
    // Remove the old toolbar.
    self.oldToolbar.alpha = 0;

    // Fade the new toolbar in.
    self.newToolbar.alpha = 1;
}];
```

This example assumes that you have already loaded your other toolbar into the `newToolbar` property. Let me know if you need further assistance or any explanation.

Comment: How would I bring a new toolbar into view?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an odd one... this is a bit hacky but should be perfectly fine:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    // Remove the old toolbar.
    self.oldToolbar.alpha = 0;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //add code to change toolbar.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        // Fade the new toolbar in.
        self.newToolbar.alpha = 1;
    }];
}];
```